# Proving $\frac{n^2}{n-3}$ diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

I need to prove that  $$\frac{n^2}{n-3}$$ diverges

For that, I need to prove that, given $\epsilon>0$, we have $n_0$ which depends on $\epsilon$, such that:

$$n>n_0 \implies \frac{n^2}{n-3}>\epsilon$$

I tried to write down the equation and find a relation on $n$, by solving the inequaality $n^2>\epsilon(n-3)$ but the solution is not valid for every $\epsilon$. For example, [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5E2-a*n%2B3a%20%3E%200) gives $$n>1/2(\epsilon+\sqrt{(\epsilon-12)\epsilon)}$$
for $\epsilon>12$. Any ideas in how to prove it **by definition**? Also, which is the easiest way to prove without being by definition?

Comment: Just let $m=n-3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \frac{n^2}{n-3} > \frac{n^2}{n} = n, \forall n > 3$$

Comment: This is much better.

Answer (score 2):

Why bother solving it exactly? That just obfuscates what's going on; the point is that $$\frac{n^2}{n - 3} \approx n$$
so choose $N \approx 1/\epsilon$. In fact, if we set $N = 42/\epsilon$, then it's easy to prove that 
$$n \ge N \implies \frac{n^2}{n - 3} > \epsilon.$$

Comment: Along those same lines, one could argue that $n^2\gt (n-3)^2$. Now just show that $n-3$ diverges.

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{n^2}{n-3} = n+3 + \dfrac{9}{n-3}> n+3, \forall n \geq 4$. Thus for any $M  > 0$, choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N > M-3$, then if $n > N \Rightarrow n + 3 > (M-3)+3 = M\Rightarrow \dfrac{n^2}{n-3} > M$, and this implies that the sequence diverges.